# Is it possible to automate Visio using a third party?

Tags: automation, visio, office-automation

We are trying to create a `Visio` project file and to process it with an external tool to generate a `json` file that a web app can read to create a decision tree based on the `json` contents.

We know about 3rd parties to automate MS Word files but no idea if there are others dealing with `Visio` files.

Google didn't return anything valid as per Automation it always returns links to how to program macros on it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to automate Visio: macros, .net plugins, python, pascal, even windows powershell.

But if your final aim is getting Visio to the web, you may try the following link.

http://unmanagedvisio.com/category/svgexport/

The tool exports the drawing to an SVG embedded in an HTML file with Javascript functionality. Definitely worth a look.